# В Assistant Editor в Automatic не отображаются нужные мне файлы, не получается создать ссылки Outlet

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Всем привет. Совсем недавно начала изучать Objective-C и столкнулась с такой проблемой. Мне нужно создать ссылки на объекты в файле DetailViewController.h
При открытии Assistant Editor слева отображается мой StoryBoard, а справа код, но не тот, который мне нужен. При попытке его открыть через Automatic его там просто нет, а если открываю через Manual, то их просто не получается создать. Я тащу стрелку, а создать ссылку она не хочет. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не указали класс в Storyboard.
Это делается вот тут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое)